# Two functions not working together (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so I guess it is a problem of priority but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my problem.

I have two function (jQuery) working around **select** tags.
The first one permit to take the value of the option selected and put it in a span (right next to the select tag). It is use to show the value selected by the user.

**[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/6rrnz44g/16/)**

I'll show you it's not too long :

### The ***select*** I'm working on :

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
     <label>Kitten(s)</label>
     <div class="selector">
         <select>
            <option value="1" >01</option>
            <option value="2">02</option>
            ...
         </select><span class="custom-select"></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

### jQuery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(afficheSelect);
function afficheSelect(){
     $('select').on('keyup change', function(){
         $(this).next('span').empty(); /* Empty the span when a change occur */ 
         $(this).next('span').append($(this).val()); /* Show the number selected */
     });
}
```

My second function, *show a number of select in function of the first value selected*.

Let say you choose 3 kittens it will do 3 **Select** where you can specify their color (for example).

### 2nd function : (You dont have to read it to answer my question :) )

```
jQuery(document).ready(affKitt);
function affKitt(){
    $('select').on('keyup change', function(){
    $('#test').empty();
    nbK = $(this).val();

    if(nbK > 0){
        html = "<label id='bug7'>Indicate the color of the kitten :</label>";

        for(var i=1; i <= nbK; i++) /* Show number of select */
        {
            else
            {
                html +='<div class="col-xs-4"><div class="selector"><select id="colorKitten'+i+'" name="colorKitten'+i+'">';
                for(var k=2; k <= 11; k++) /* Show option (allways the same) */
                {
                    html +="<option value='colorSelected'>Blue, Grey ....</option>";
                }
                /* Closing tags */
                html +="</select><span class='custom-select'></span></div></div>";
            }
        }
        $('#colorKittens').append(html); /* This is a div under a certaine place */
    }

    });
}
```

And now ***Here is my problem*** : The first function dont apply to the select generate by my second function... Why that ???

Thank you to anyone who could answer this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Good I've managed it.

It was as easy as calling the function into the function of creation : See the Fiddle here  : **[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/6rrnz44g/19/)**

A simple  `afficheSelect();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the `event handler` for your `change event` on the `variable` `html` before it is appended to the element `$('#colorKittens').append(html);`.

**Solution**

```
// Make the variable for HTML a jQuery object, so you can apply jQuery.fn to it
var jHtml = $(html);

// Check that jHtml is not EMPTY
if(jHtml.length) {
    jHtml.afficheSelect();
    $('#colorKittens').append(jHtml);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select class='my_select_box'>
    <option value='blue'>Blue Kitten</option>
    <option value='red'>Red Kitten</option>
    <option value='red'>Yellow Kitten</option>
</select>
<span class='mynextelement'></span>
```

**afficheSelect**

```
jQuery.fn.afficheSelect = function() {
     var next_span_element = $(this).next('span');
     $(this).change(function() {
        var selected_option_value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();   
         next_span_element.html(selected_option_value); /* Show the number selected */
     });
};
```

I found the `span` element, can't be found; while within the `function` of `.change`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/killrawr/6rrnz44g/).

Comment: Hum I've got this error : SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

Comment: Yup seen, its working but not resolving my problem :/

Comment: Ok I think I get what happen I'll try on my board and tell you if there is no change :)

Comment: @Killawr However I turn it; it tell me that jHtml.afficheSelect() is not a function. Shall I put the function inside my first function ?

Comment: Nop still not working :/ Same error message : jHtml.aff... is not a function

Comment: Check out the `JSFiddle`, I have added... if you follow this, it should work. Regards

Comment: This is not exactly it :/ I'll do a Fiddle :)

Comment: JsFiddle added (mostly in english this time)

Comment: victory See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(afficheSelect);
function afficheSelect(){
     $('select').on('keyup change', function(){
         $(this).next('span').empty(); /* Empty the span when a change occur */ 
         $(this).next('span').append($(this).val()); /* Show the number selected */
     });
}
```

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(afficheSelect);
function afficheSelect(){
     $('select').on('keyup change', function(){
         $(this).next('span').html($(this).val()); /* Show the number selected */
     });
}
```